# Flutter margin onFocus FocusNode

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do I set the margin from the edge when the focus hits a specific `FocusNode`?

As you can see from the video, there is an indentation on top of the buttons, but when you scroll the screen and return the focus to the button, it sticks to the top of the screen, it's understandable, the button is on the screen and in focus, but how to make a small offset from the top?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Container(
 margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:  (focusnode.hasFocus) ? 10 : 0),
 child: Text((focusnode.hasFocus) ? 'In Focus' : 'No Focus');
);
```

Comment: Yeah, it really works, but is it really good solution?

Comment: for sure, bro !